# How to apply "set number" to vi on root?

Tags: linux, bash, centos, vi

I'm using vi on centos 6.5 and added "set number" script to /etc/bashrc in order to look line numbers whenever boot.

It works well to show it on user login but not root.

How to apply "set number" of /etc/bashrc to root?

This is on user login.

[image]

Here is on root login.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this question.

I added a script of alias vi="vim" to /root/.bashrc like this:

```
  1 # .bashrc
  2 
  3 # User specific aliases and functions
  4 
  5 alias rm='rm -i'
  6 alias cp='cp -i'
  7 alias mv='mv -i'
  8 alias vi="vim"   
  9 
 10 # Source global definitions
 11 if [ -f /etc/bashrc ]; then
 12         . /etc/bashrc
 13 fi
```